# Azure and the MVC2 Web Role template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, azure

I tried creating a Cloud project in VS2010. When I try to add the ASP.NET MVC2 Web Role template and click okay then I get the following message appear in a dialog box.

> The project template references by the roletemplatedata.xml file cannot be found

I tried a remove and reinstall of the 1.3 SDK but that didn't help. I tried a reinstall of the MVC2 tools but that didn't help. I wish VS2010 gave a bit more information. There are many roletemplatedata.xml files and it doesn't give me a clue as to what is missing.

Anyone else have a similar problem?

Comment: I've the same problem on one of my machine...

Answer (score 1):

Go to Add/Remove Programs and add Visual Web Developer feature (if it's not installed) to the VS Setup. If it is already installed then uninstall this feature once and reinstall again.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the following blog entry helps you:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/05/15/creating-mvc-2-web-role-in-visual-studio-2010-cause-error-quot-the-project-template-referenced-by-the-roletemplatedata-xml-file-cannot-be-found-quot.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What do you have here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CloudService
```

Execute:

```
tree /F "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CloudService"
```